# How to access my domain cookie on another domain inside script file

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

My domain name: `app.xyz.com`

My script file load from: `app.xyz.com/abc.js`

Client domain name: `abcd.com`

In client domain`(abcd.com)` my script tag`(app.xyz.com/abc.js)` is loaded.

I want to access my domain`(app.xyz.com)` cookie inside my script file`(app.xyz.com/abc.js)` which is loaded in client domain`(abcd.com)`.

How can I achieve this task?